# Dynamically create wrapper for unmanaged assembly?

Tags: c#, c++, reflection, unmanaged, managed

I have an application where you select a managed dll and the methods are listed along with parameters. I am able to select a method and parameters and later execute the method.

Now, I wonder if it is possible to do something similar with c/c++ dlls from my .NET code? I am thinking that it could be possible because when I select a reference to a c++ dll in Visual Studio I am able to access methods and so on?

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: You should consider marking some answers to your previous questions.  It is likely to help get more people to want to help you over time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that C++ doesn't support any form of [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29), so there isn't a (standard) way to get information about all of the method parameters and info required to build this wrapper automatically.

There are tools to ease this wrapper generation, however, such as [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).  This does still require user input, however, and is not an automatic process.